# What is 'PermSize' in Java?

Tags: java, memory

I was going through the document in [Java Memory Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) and in that I came across PermSize which I couldn't understand. The document says that it stores, "JVM stores its metadata", but I couldn't exactly get what is meant by metadata. I was googling and somewhere I read it stores a value object (user defined object).

What kind of objects are stored there? An example with an explanation would be great.

Comment: The default value is 64m for 64 bit VMs. We increased it to `512m` for a tomcat server running 8 rails apps. `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m`. Tomcat with many class definitions itself needs a big PerSize and with ruby, ruby on rails combined with jruby ..need a huge PermSize.

Comment: Note that the Permanent Generation (and with it PermSize parameters) are going away in Java 8. They are replaced by the "Metaspace". See http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html

Comment: @sleske BitDefender blocks that page, stating it contains malware.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

A quick definition of the "permanent generation":

> "The permanent generation is used to
>   hold reflective data of the VM itself
>   such as class objects and method
>   objects. These reflective objects are
>   allocated directly into the permanent
>   generation, and it is sized
>   independently from the other
>   generations." [[ref]](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html)

In other words, this is where class definitions go (and this explains why you may get the message `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` if an application loads a large number of classes and/or on redeployment).

Note that **`PermSize`** is additional to the **`-Xmx`** value set by the user on the JVM options. But **`MaxPermSize`** allows for the JVM to be able to grow the **`PermSize`** to the amount specified. Initially when the VM is loaded, the **`MaxPermSize`** will still be the default value (32mb for `-client` and 64mb for `-server`) but will not actually take up that amount until it is needed. On the other hand, if you were to set BOTH **`PermSize`** and **`MaxPermSize`** to 256mb, you would notice that the overall heap has increased by 256mb additional to the **`-Xmx`** setting.

Answer (score 24):

[This blog post](http://narencoolgeek.blogspot.com/2007/08/heap-size-and-perm-size.html) gives a nice explanation and some background. Basically, the "permanent generation" (whose size is given by PermSize) is used to store things that the JVM has to allocate space for, but which will not (normally) be garbage-collected (hence "permanent") (+). That means for example loaded classes and static fields.

There is also a [FAQ on garbage collection](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html) directly from Sun, which answers some questions about the permanent generation. Finally, here's a [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) with a lot of technical detail.

(+) Actually parts of the permanent generation *will* be GCed, e.g. class objects will be removed when a class is unloaded. But that was uncommon when the permanent generation was introduced into the JVM, hence the name.

Answer (score 11):

The permament pool contains everything that is not your application data, but rather things required for the VM: typically it contains interned strings, the byte code of defined classes, but also other "not yours" pieces of data.

Answer (score 0):

lace to store your loaded class definition and metadata. If a large code-base project is loaded, the insufficient Perm Gen size will cause the popular Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen.