# Quartz schedular exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz schedular.

After some time of deployment it is showing folowing Exception

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8084-exec-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-bio-8084-exec-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

How to resolve this exception.

Comment: what kind of program is it, how is it started? r u using `java MyClass` to start it

Comment: It is showing exception while redeployment

Comment: How do you know this is due to using quartz?

Comment: Showing error stack of  quarts

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Maximum size property of the jvm while starting jvm

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```

You can read more about the option [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634216/what-is-permsize-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356416/xxmaxpermsize-with-or-without-xxpermsize)

Comment: My shared server heap size is 64Mb. There i am not getting  option for  heap size setting

Comment: @user2302288 it is not a heap problem, Perm space is a different space. which is the container used and how is it started

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely it's not a heap problem.

Permgen space problem occurs if there is any error while loading a class. So, here your class is not loaded properly
meaning you have a less permgen ( different from heap size and is also configurable attribute in jvm ).

Comment: How to detect which class in not loading properly

Comment: I have no idea about this but the classloading problem is solely due to the fact that there isn't any free space to load your class definition in memory. Rather , I would advice to first try increasing the Permgen size and then to see the consequence.