# JAVA VM memory options 32bit less than 2g won't work

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a 32 bit debian machine running and want to increase my tomcat's memory. I tried this:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx1536M -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1536m"`
 but i still get this error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Why is that? I know 32 bit can only use up to 2g but 1.5 should easily work...

```
SYSTEM: DEBIAN WHEEZY 32 BIT
JAVA: ORACLE JAVA 7u55 32bit
```

Comment: How much RAM space you have?

Comment: 32 gigabytes. it is a rack server :)

Comment: Then why in the world are you running a 32-bit operating system on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xms and Permsize add up (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634424/821202), so you try to allocate 1024m + 1024m = 2048m initially.

Comment: thanks i set it to 1023 min and 1024 max on both and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

My JVM config for a SUSE 32 bit and is working fine:

```
-Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=128m XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: thanks but the other answer was better... My project also needs the high perm size as well as high working memory