# How many characters can a Java StringBuilder hold?

Tags: java, stringbuilder, java-6, capacity

Does StringBuilder have a limit of characters for maximum capacity in JAVA.

```
StringBuilder url=new StringBuilder();

stmt = connnection.createStatement();
String sql="SOME QUERY";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
    String emailId=rs.getString("USER_EMAIL_ID");
     url.append(emailId);  
}
```

does StringBuilder variable 'url' have a maximum capacity, or it can hold everything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it has limitation in capacity of max integer which 2147483647(technically).

`StringBuilder` internally holds chracters in [`char[]`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder) object, and array has limitation in size. [read more about it on other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382531/why-i-cant-create-an-array-with-large-size)

Comment: and what happens if it exceeds the maximum limit?

Answer (score 1):

Java 9 introduced [JEP 254: Compact Strings](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254). This allows storing strings more space-efficiently by storing characters in a byte array. If all characters are Latin 1, one byte is used per char, otherwise two bytes per char are used.

So the answer is: If compact strings are enabled (the default) and your `StringBuilder` contains only Latin 1 chars, the maximum size is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`<sup>*</sup>, otherwise it is `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2`<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup> Or slightly less, see ["Do Java arrays have a maximum size?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038392/4288506)

Answer (score 0):

If you go through with this link this may clear you more [Oracle Docs String Builder Buffer Capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

Now you want to declare the Capacity of any StringBuilder Class, then one Constructor `StringBuilder(int initCapacity)` is defined for this.

> `StringBuilder(int initCapacity)` :- Creates an empty string builder with the specified initial capacity.

Here because of parameter as `int` the maximum capacity that a `StringBuilder` Class can is reach will be `2147483647`.

there are various method regarding this context of Capacity in `StringBuilder` Class, those methods also consider the parameters of type `int`.

> **void setLength(int newLength)** :- Sets the length of the character sequence. If newLength is less than length(), the last characters in the character sequence are truncated. If newLength is greater than length(), null characters are added at the end of the character sequence.
>
> **void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)** :- Ensures that the capacity is at least equal to the specified minimum.

these methods also takes argument as of `int` type . So, Using these methods or contructors you will able to generate a object with max capacity of `2147483647`.

Comment: None of the method you shown, has anything to do the the *maximum* capacity, which is what the question is about. The link you provided doesn't say anything about maximum capacity either. As for your last sentence, just because the parameter is an `int`, doesn't mean that you won't get an error if you give the maximum possible integer value, and `new StringBuilder(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` will get `OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` regardless of how much memory you assign to the VM. In short, no part of this answer is relevant and accurate for the question.

Comment: @Andreas yes You are right. If sufficient memory is not available then it will raise an `OutOfMemory` JVM Error. I have not mentioned the error.

Thanks

Comment: Even if enough memory *is* available, doesn't mean that `new char[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` will work. The maximum size of an array may be limited by other constraints, which are platform dependent.