# Why it's impossible to create an array of MAX_INT size in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, garbage-collection, jvm, cpu-word

I have read some answers for this question([Why I can't create an array with large size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382531/why-i-cant-create-an-array-with-large-size) and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029587) and I don't understand the following. 
*"In the GC code we pass around the size of objects in words as an int."* As I know the size of a word in JVM is 4 bytes. According to this, if we pass around the size of long array of large size (for example, MAX_INT - 5) in words as an int, we must get OutOfMemoryException with *Requested array size exceeds VM limit* because the size is too large for int even without size of header. So why arrays of different types have the same limit on max count of elements?

Comment: They don't. The limit is that both the allocated size in words and the number of elements must fit in a signed 32-bit integer. For arrays of reference types, that size is the same as the number of elements (barring possibly header words). For byte/short the size cap won't be hit. On 32-bit platforms I'd expect a long[] to be limited to axint/2 items (roughly).

Comment: There is answer to this question in your question (first comment): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029587

Comment: @Zastai If it was true, there wouldn't  be any questions but actually for example I can't create an array of bytes with MAX_INT size

Answer (score 2):

Only addressing the *why arrays of different types have the same limit on max count of elements?* part:

Because it doesn't matter to much in practical reality; but allows the code implementing the JVM to be simpler.

When there is only **one** limit; that is the same for all kinds of arrays; then you can deal all arrays with that code. Instead of having a lot of type-specific code.

And given the fact that the people that need "large" arrays can still create them; and only those that need **really really large** arrays are impacted; why spent that effort?

Comment: It would be clear if that one limit was based on long type. I can't understand how I can create a long array of (MAX_INT - 1) if it's impossible to index words of that array using an int variable

Comment: I have to admit I was in a rush when writing my answer. I might update it tomorrow if you don't receive better input by then.

Comment: After seeing the code as cited in the other answer, I don’t have the feeling that this made the code simpler, or well, the behavior doesn’t even seem to be intentional. And “really really large” depends on the point of view. `new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` isn’t that impressive nowadays and it feels quiet strange not being able to allocate that, while allocating `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE-8]`, almost four times that memory, works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the jdk sources as far as I can tell (I'm looking at jdk-9); also after writing it I am not sure if it should be a comment instead (and if it answers your question), but it's too long for a comment...

First the error is thrown from `hotspot/src/share/vm/oops/arrayKlass.cpp` here:

```
if (length > arrayOopDesc::max_array_length(T_ARRAY)) {
   report_java_out_of_memory("Requested array size exceeds VM limit");
    ....
}
```

Now, `T_ARRAY` is actually an enum of type `BasicType` that looks like this:

```
public static final BasicType T_ARRAY = new BasicType(tArray);
// tArray is an int with value = 13
```

That is the first indication that when computing the maximum size, jdk does not *care* what that array will hold (the `T_ARRAY` does not specify what types will that array hold).

Now the method that actually validates the maximum array size looks like this:

```
 static int32_t max_array_length(BasicType type) {
      assert(type >= 0 && type < T_CONFLICT, "wrong type");
      assert(type2aelembytes(type) != 0, "wrong type");

      const size_t max_element_words_per_size_t =
      align_size_down((SIZE_MAX/HeapWordSize - header_size(type)), MinObjAlignment);
      const size_t max_elements_per_size_t =
      HeapWordSize * max_element_words_per_size_t / type2aelembytes(type);
      if ((size_t)max_jint < max_elements_per_size_t) {
         // It should be ok to return max_jint here, but parts of the code
         // (CollectedHeap, Klass::oop_oop_iterate(), and more) uses an int for
         // passing around the size (in words) of an object. So, we need to avoid
         // overflowing an int when we add the header. See CRs 4718400 and 7110613.
         return align_size_down(max_jint - header_size(type), MinObjAlignment);
      }
       return (int32_t)max_elements_per_size_t;
}
```

I did not dive too much into the code, but it is based on `HeapWordSize`; which is `8 bytes at least`. [here](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-December/010326.html) is a good reference (I tried to look it up into the code itself, but there are too many references to it).

Comment: Why HeapWordSize is 8 bytes at least? I found here http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp that MaxHeapSize = sizeof(HeapWord) and HeapWord class has only one field of char* type. It means that size of HeapWordSize depends on architecture and may be 4 bytes as well

Comment: @Wild_Wind you're right and I'm not. At this point I have the same struggle understating and you do.

Comment: But why on Earth does `max_array_length` receive a parameter when it is supposed to be always `T_ARRAY`? I first thought, it is actually supposed to be the element type, as indicated by the use in `type2aelembytes(type)`, but then, it uses `header_size(type)`. This is inconsistent as hell. And the size in words can only overflow when the element type’s size is at least the word size, which implies an object size of `Integer.MAX_VALUE×word size`, for 32 bit JVMs impossible to allocate and for 64 Bit JVMs only applying to `long[]` and `double[]`, irrelevant to any JVM with less than 16 GB heap…

Comment: Have looked up up the code, the parameter *is* the array element type and the cited caller is only responsible for allocating an array of array. The `header_size(type)` function is also dedicate for returning the size of the header of an array of the specified type. So this implementation *does* care about the array’s element type. The problem is that nonsensical `max_elements_per_size_t` which may report a number of elements that Java can never allocate (higher than 2³¹).