# Can not create 2³¹-1 sized byte[] in HotSpot

Tags: java, arrays, jvm-hotspot

I always thought the maximum array size in Java is 2³¹-1 however I fail to create a `byte[]` that is larger than 2³¹-4 on HotSpot. If i do `new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` on HotSpot I get:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

I wrote the following program to find out the maximum array size

```
  private static void printMaxArraySize() {
    int maxArraySize = findMaxArraySize();
    System.out.println("max array size: " + maxArraySize);
    System.out.println("max array size - Integer.MAX_VALUE: " + (Integer.MAX_VALUE - maxArraySize));
  }

  private static int findMaxArraySize() {
    for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; i >= 0; i--) {
      try {
        byte[] data = new byte[i];
        if (System.identityHashCode(data) == 42) {
          System.out.println();
        }
        return i;
      } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // ignore
      }
    }
    throw new AssertionError("not able to create a byte[0]");
  }
```

And even with `-Xmx60g -Xms60g -XX:+UseSerialGC` it prints, I tested with JDK 8 and JDK 10

```
max array size: 2147483644
max array size - Integer.MAX_VALUE: 3
```

OpenJ9 on the other hand seems to support 2³¹-1 sized `byte[]` just fine

```
max array size: 2147483647
max array size - Integer.MAX_VALUE: 0
```

**Edit**

After formulating the question SO suggests the issue is [JDK-8059914](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059914)

**Edit 2**

The bug suggests `size_t` is now used instead of `int` so the object size limit should really be 4GB and `new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` should work.

**Edit 3**

If I lower `-Xmx` I also get `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2`.

Comment: On my Java 10, I get `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2`, which is much better than what I got in the past, the last time I checked the JVM’s limit. While I always knew about the existence of a JVM specific limitation, I never read an explanation about why. Now, reading JDK-8059914, I must say that, cough, it is…not very convincing. If the object type is supposed to fit into a 32 bit `int`, that will fail for any array type except `byte[]` and `boolean[]` anyway, as all other types require more than one byte per element. In contrast, there’s never a problem with `byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` and 64 Bit `int`…

Comment: So, it is connected to the compressed oops resp. compressed klass pointer feature, which is available for heaps smaller than 32GB (unless you change the object alignment). Your question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43592109/2711488) and there is [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31382531/2711488). There more I read about it, the less sense does all that make to me.