# Update the eclipse.ini to increase heap but no effect in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I use Eclipse Kepler SR2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and the following is my eclipse.ini

---

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
3072m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/DevTools/xulrunner -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.Defau$
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=3072m
-Xms2048m
-Xmx3072m
```

---

But in eclipse the heap size shows the following:

```
397 of 453M
```

And if I mouse over on the Heap size info it shows:

```
Heap size: 397M of total: 453M max: 455M mark: 397M
```

I am expecting the max value should be close to 3072M since that is what being set in eclipse.ini

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve it ? I am having similar problem. My eclipse based ide, does not reflect an increase in heapsize, no matter how much i increase it in the eclipse.ini

Comment: I ended up uninstalling Eclipse Kepler and installed Luna.

Comment: Why did you assign a `-XX:MaxPermSize=3072m`? You shouldn't usually don't need it to be *that* big. Check out [What is 'PermSize' in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634216/).

Comment: @AndiSetiyadi were you able to resolve the issue, i.e. being able to set the heap size according to need, with the Luna installation?

Answer (score 0):

Each entry in the eclipse.ini **must** be on a separate line, your line:

```
-vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/DevTools/xulrunner -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.Defau$
```

will not be recognized as the start of the VMargs. It should be:

```
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/DevTools/xulrunner
... more args on separate lines ...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it has no effect.  I ended up uninstalling the Kepler and install Luna.  Under Luna, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think manual installations cause such problems as my eclipse ignores eclipse.ini completely when run via the launcher in Ubuntu (14.04) (used `lock to launcher`). So the workaround for me is to run it any other way. Desktop icon works too. Property `Path` must be set within that file.